# Conflicting persistence unit definitions

Tags: eclipse, jpa

Spring 3.1.1
Maven 3.0.4
JPA
Eclipse wtp indigo

Hello,
I am getting the following exception on server startup. I have just one persistence.xml in my project. Any ideas? Thanks Eric

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'cassandra_pu': file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cassandra/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cassandra/WEB-INF/classes/
>   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:362)
>   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:326)
>   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:235)
>   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>   ... 62 more

My context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan base-package="hamacher.cassandra.controller" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="hamacher.cassandra.dao" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="hamacher.cassandra.service" />  
    <context:annotation-config />  



    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>  
    </bean>  

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">    
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="hamacher.cassandra.entity"/>   
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cassandra_pu"/>  
  </bean>    


    <tx:annotation-driven />  
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">  
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
</bean>  


</beans>
```

My persistence.xml file is in META-INF where it should be:

```
   <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"  
        version="2.0">  
        <persistence-unit name="cassandra_pu">  
            <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>       
            <properties>            
                <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>  
                <property name="kundera.port" value="9160"/>  
                <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="KunderaExamples"/>  
                <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>  
                <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClientFactory" />  
                <property name="kundera.cache.provider.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider"/>  
                <property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-test.xml"/>                  
            </properties>       
        </persistence-unit>  
    </persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding,

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="emf-p"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml" /> -->
            <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="personnel_cass_pu" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

To define your persistence.xml location with Spring bean.

You can also refer:
https://github.com/xamry/twitample/blob/master/src/main/resources/appContext.xml

for `persistence.xml` specific configuration.