# Conflicting persistence unit definitions exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, maven-3

I am getting the following exception on server startup. I have just one persistence.xml in my project. Any ideas?

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'TRAVEL_SYSTEM_UNIT': file:/D:/TravelSystem/workspace-sts/Travel_System-EAR/EarContent/APP-INF/classes/, file:/D:/TravelSystem/workspace-sts/Travel_System-dataaccess/target/classes/
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:362)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:326)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

My context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dataaccess" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mysql" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SYSTEM_UNIT"></property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.dataaccess.model"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"></property>
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property> -->

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>


</beans>
```

My persistence.xml file is in META-INF where it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="TRAVEL_SYSTEM_UNIT" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysql</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
            <property name="default_batch_fetch_size" value="25" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
<!--            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> -->

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" 
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

using 3.1.2.RELEASE Maven 3.0.4

Comment: If you defined the persistence unit in Spring XML config, you no longer need the persistence.xml file.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo can add more description for solution

Comment: Read [Spring JPA Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa) where they explain it all in detail. But bottom line you can either use a persistence.xml and tell Spring to use it, or you can define everything in Spring and avoid the use of the persistence.xml file.

Comment: @abdelhady will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656848/conflicting-persistence-unit-definitions) be of any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add below configuration to  My context file:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="pum"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/persistence-test.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

On window I put *META-INF/persistence.xml* under **src/java/resources**.
Then I import same project to Ubuntu, this problem appeared. And it is fixed after I moved *META-INF/persistence.xml* to **src/main/webapp.**